# How to import a module from a file I created in Python?

Tags: python, pycharm, python-import

I made the file Latinobjects.py, and created the class `Translation` and function `create_translations` in it. I'm trying to access them from the file I'm working in, but it keeps saying the file doesn't exist when it does. They're all in the same project and folder in Pycharm. I have tried:

```
import Latinobjects
```

and

```
from Latinobjects import Translation, create_translations
```

both variants produce:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file '/Users/xxx/PycharmProjects/LearningLatin/latinobjects': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I have manually gone to the file in finder. ‎⁨It is there: ‎⁨Macintosh HD⁩ ▸ ⁨Users⁩ ▸ ⁨xxx ▸ ⁨PycharmProjects⁩ ▸ ⁨LearningLatin⁩ . I don't understand what the problem is.

Why is this happening? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what about the capital "L" in latinobjects which does not appear in the error message. Have you tried importing it that way?

Answer (score 1):

I see you are using PyCharm. Are these scripts in the same project? If not try moving the script to the same directory as your main script you are trying to run. It would also be helpful if you posted your file structure for us to help you. I am considering that you need to `from LearningLatin import Latinobjects` instead, and then maybe you could use `Latinobjects.Translation`? This is just speculation until you post your file structure.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your import is checking for `latinobjects`, not `Latinobjects`.

Try:

- Create directory /Users⁩/xxx/⁨PycharmProjects⁩/LearningLatin/**latinobjects**
- Under the new directory, create `__init__.py` with the following
- Contents of `__init__.py`:

```
from .Latinobjects import *
```

- Move Latinobjects.py to latinobjects/Latinobjects.py

Run code with import statement.